# Ajax request to API not working in fresh installation of Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

Running the following commands:

`$ laravel new app`

`$ composer install`

`$ php artisan make:auth`

Fill new DB info.

`$ php artisan migrate`

`$ yarn install`

Hit /register and make a new user, now I'm logged in into Laravel. I open the JavaScript console and I write the following:

`> axios.get('/api/user').then(res => console.log(res.data));`

Following I get: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user 401 (Unauthorized)

My headers are:

`GET /api/user HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: QmU4zkAA5N9BVoZsJEX4cQIn3UHwzNmFEwZkl8vy
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6ImFcL1JYeFZnV1piVG5jRFZYWnFKVUpnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImczYmxMZW1Fa2xPaVRwUVQyUTJ0Wm1UNHo0NWNxZkRJazFKY3o3R05XTE9KcVNyMDlzOE80NitpZ1FBcjJOUXJGYXl1bnJyN2hFMksyR2RcL1RobWNcL0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjY5NGUzNzc1MjNmODdiYmJlYzI2YzI4YWQzMGQwMWY2MWVjYmUzZThkNDZjYWEzM2MxMzFlNmRkMzRlY2Q0OTcifQ==
X-CSRF-TOKEN: QmU4zkAA5N9BVoZsJEX4cQIn3UHwzNmFEwZkl8vy
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImFcL1JYeFZnV1piVG5jRFZYWnFKVUpnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImczYmxMZW1Fa2xPaVRwUVQyUTJ0Wm1UNHo0NWNxZkRJazFKY3o3R05XTE9KcVNyMDlzOE80NitpZ1FBcjJOUXJGYXl1bnJyN2hFMksyR2RcL1RobWNcL0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjY5NGUzNzc1MjNmODdiYmJlYzI2YzI4YWQzMGQwMWY2MWVjYmUzZThkNDZjYWEzM2MxMzFlNmRkMzRlY2Q0OTcifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImRtZzdPUElaY1dcL1hLWHJPZVkwaW5RPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IitrVm9GOW5TQTdWZldJY3VlWU5EeWVBRitIVjVrYXpkWGhmWmJlWjJrTmlCWVZ0VUkwdEFrY3VoU2ZCMnRKMnlCV29pQ3NVa0ROdHEyaXlLMWhuWTd3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiJhMGE0ZTg5NTlkYzlkYmM2MjBhMjNmYTA2ZjUyYmE0N2RlMzVmNjA4Zjg3MDZhMDEzMDM1MGJjOWUzNzg5NDk3In0%3D`

Anyone going through a similar situation?

Comment: You could consider to solve this with Laravel Passport and (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client)[Password Grant Tokens].  With this you could create a personal access_token to connect with your API.

Comment: @piscator, as soon as I tried to pull Passport package inside config/app.php, it would say that class auth doesn't exist. Didn't find anything about it either. I'll give it another try.

Comment: Are you using the `auth` middleware or `auth:api`?

Comment: @Diederik, it's an out of the box installation, the action above by default triggers an `auth:api`